# How can I move a shared_ptr's data?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, move-semantics

I have an easy question about shared pointers and move semantics. Imagine that I have a class with a private member variable like this:

```
class C
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> buffer;
}
```

I need to provide public getters and setters. The getter seems obvious:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> C::GetBuffer()
{
    return buffer;
}
```

However, being new to C++ I'm having trouble writing the setter. I could do something like this:

```
void C::SetBuffer(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> input)
{
    buffer = input;
}
```

However that results in a copy of input to buffer, but I don't really want the caller to have shared ownership. Instead I want to move the data. I tried to solve this with:

```
void C::SetBuffer(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>>& input)
{
    buffer(std::move(input));
}
```

But this is an error: "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type."

Can somebody help me understand:
1. What is going on here?
2. How to best implement the setter?

Comment: When you assign from one shared pointer to another, it's only the *pointer* that gets copied, not what it points to. And of course the reference counter will be increased.

Comment: If you don't want to share ownership with the caller, make the argument a plain `vector<uint8_t>` instead of `shared_ptr<vector<uint8_t>>`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg At [http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/] it says, "When you pass by value, you have to copy the argument (usually) on entry to the function, and then destroy it (always) on function exit." Does that mean that the only thing copied is the pointer, not the whole vector? The rest of that post seems to argue against passing shared_ptr by value except in limited circumstances, but I might be misunderstanding it.

Comment: How come it doesn't bother you that you are giving the caller shared ownership in `GetBuffer`, but it does bother you that you are taking shared ownership in `SetBuffer`? Do you or don't you want shared ownership? If you don't, why are you using `shared_ptr` in the first place?

Comment: You might want to check a [`std::shared_ptr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), especially about the [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D).

Comment: if you want to move the data that would be `*buffer = std::move(*input);` but I think you should think carefully about the previous comments before making that change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the error you're getting by writing this:

```
void C::SetBuffer( std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t> > &input ) {
    buffer = move(input);
}
```

This will call `shared_ptr`'s move-assignment operator, which will pilfer `input`.  However, this won't really stop the caller from having shared ownership.  Once you accept (or dispense) a `shared_ptr` from/to an unknown client, you don't have much in the way of control about who shares ownership.  Even if `input` is pilfered, there's no reason to expect that `input` was the only copy of the `shared_ptr` you just received.  If, for example, the function that called `SetBuffer()` took whatever became `input` from ***its*** caller by value, that higher-level copy of the pointer will continue to share ownership.

Note that your getter has a similar issue.  You're returning a `shared_ptr` to your own internal object (and what's more, it's a `shared_ptr`-to-non-`const`, so the client can modify the shared state) and wherever that `shared_ptr` gets passed around after you provide it, those copies will also share (mutable) ownership.

If you really want to ensure you have exclusive ownership, you can hold a `unique_ptr` instead of a `shared_ptr` and have your getter pass back a `const`-reference, and your setter take either a `unique_ptr` or a value.

Comment: N.B. you almost always want to qualify `std::move()` to prevent ADL

Comment: @JonathanWakely, what's wrong with ADL?  I usually prefer to enable ADL in all cases unless it causes a specific problem, because I've seen too many code instances where it was unintentionally (and harmfully) disabled.  In this case, there is no way any other overload could interfere, but even in cases where there could be, usually there won't be.

Comment: If you want to cast an object to an rvalue to enable move semantics then you want `std::move` not some other `move` so why take a chance of ADL kicking in? If someone changes the value_type of the vector to a user-defined type in another namespace they now have to audit every use of `move` to add the `std::` qual because you didn't add it. The inventor of move semantics says: ["**all** uses of move and forward need to be qualified: std::move, std::forward. ... std::move and std::forward are not customization points (like swap)."](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2007-08/msg00034.html)

Comment: Regarding the last point of the answer, another option would be to return a shared_ptr to const. This would eliminate the danger of dangling references.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to allow a caller to pass sole ownership of a buffer to your object, you should accept it by `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`:

```
void C::SetBuffer(std::unique_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> input)
{
    buffer = std::move(input);
}
```

Rvalue `unique_ptr` is convertible to `shared_ptr` for exactly this purpose.

Comment: What is the point in taking a unique_ptr when there's anyway a getter for the internal shared_ptr? Wouldn't it just make life easier to accept a shared_ptr to begin with?